# TSQL while loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, loops, sql-update, sum

```
UPDATE Houses 
SET    lStatus = U.codesum
FROM   Houses H
JOIN   (SELECT ref, SUM(code) AS codesum
    FROM   Users
    GROUP  BY ref) AS U ON U.ref = H.ref
```

The above code gets all users for every house (Houses table). SUMs the code column (Users table) for all users. And finally updates the result in lstatus column of the houses table.

My question is: 
I need to rewrite the query which is NOT to sum the code column. Rather I want to create case statements. for example:

```
tempvar = 0    //local variable might be required

For each user {

If code == 1 then tempvar += 5

else if code == 2 then tempvar += 10

etc

tempvar = 0;
}
```

Once we have looped through all the users for each house we can now set lStatus = tempvar.
The tempvar should then be reset to 0 for the next house.

Comment: 99% of the time, if you think "loop" in SQL Server, you're thinking the wrong way and there is a better, more efficient, set-based answer. I won't say things like always/never, but most of the time this is pretty reliable.

Comment: 99.9% of the time there is a way to get what you want without looping or using a cursor.  I know people are piling on you, but this is a bad habit to nip in the bud.  Here is another example using UDF's to solve small business problems : http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2008/07/24/cursors-setbased-and-scalar-udf/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try to avoid loops and other procedural constructs when coding SQL.  A relational database can't easily optimize such things and they often perform orders of magnitude slower than their declarative counterparts.  In this case, it seems simple enough to replace your `SUM(code)` with the `CASE` statement that you describe:

```
UPDATE Houses 
SET    lStatus = U.codesum
FROM   Houses H
JOIN   (SELECT ref, SUM(CASE code WHEN 1 THEN 5 WHEN 2 THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) AS codesum
    FROM   Users
    GROUP  BY ref) AS U ON U.ref = H.ref
```

In this way, `SUM` can still handle the duty that you imagine your temp variable would be doing.

Also, if you have many cases, you might think about putting those in a table and simply joining on that to get your sum.  This might be better to maintain.  I'm using a table variable here, but it could look like the following:

```
DECLARE @codes TABLE (
    code INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    value INT NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO @codes SELECT 1, 5
INSERT INTO @codes SELECT 2, 10

UPDATE Houses 
SET    lStatus = U.codesum
FROM   Houses H
JOIN   (SELECT a.ref, SUM(b.value) AS codesum
    FROM   Users a
    JOIN   @codes b on a.code = b.code -- Here we get the values dynamically
    GROUP  BY a.ref) AS U ON U.ref = H.ref
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Houses 
SET    lStatus = U.codesum
FROM   Houses H
JOIN   (
             SELECT ref, SUM(
                                CASE
                                    WHEN Code = 1
                                    THEN 5
                                    WHEN Code = 2
                                    THEN 10
                                END
                            ) AS codesum
             FROM   Users
             GROUP  BY ref
       ) AS U ON U.ref = H.ref
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
UPDATE Houses 
SET    lStatus = U.code
FROM   Houses H
JOIN   (
             SELECT ref, SUM(
                                CASE
                                    WHEN Code = 1
                                    THEN 5
                                    WHEN Code = 2
                                    THEN 10
                                    ELSE 0
                                END
                            ) AS code
             FROM   Users
             GROUP  BY ref
       ) AS U ON U.ref = H.ref
```